# Как экстент перевести в пиксели?

Tags: c#, xml, office

У меня имеется следующий extent

```
<wp:extent cx="5781675" cy="2637790"/>

w:drawing>
<wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="214CEEB4" wp14:editId="636CA014">
<wp:extent cx="5781675" cy="2637790"/>
<wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="9525" b="0"/>
<wp:docPr id="1" name="Рисунок 1" descr="АДПМ 12/150."/>
<wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>
<a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
<a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
<pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
<pic:nvPicPr>
<pic:cNvPr id="1" name="Рисунок 1" descr="АДПМ 12/150."/>
<pic:cNvPicPr/>
</pic:nvPicPr>
<pic:blipFill>
<a:blip r:embed="rId4">
<a:extLst>
<a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
<a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
</a:ext>
</a:extLst>
</a:blip>
<a:srcRect/>
<a:stretch>
<a:fillRect/>
</a:stretch>
</pic:blipFill>
<pic:spPr bwMode="auto">
<a:xfrm>
<a:off x="0" y="0"/>
<a:ext cx="5781675" cy="2637790"/>
</a:xfrm>
<a:prstGeom prst="rect">
<a:avLst/>
</a:prstGeom>
<a:noFill/>
<a:ln>
<a:noFill/>
</a:ln>
</pic:spPr>
</pic:pic>
</a:graphicData>
</a:graphic>
</wp:inline>
</w:drawing>
```

Как мне из этих координат получить пиксели. Никогда с таким не работал, а инфу не получается найти, как-то всё сложно, может есть простое решения?

Comment: О чем вообще речь? Где вы этот кусок XML взяли? Open XML? Тогда вот формула пересчета EMU в пиксели https://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/10/22/english-metric-units-and-open-xml/, только DPI надо знать.

Comment: Вот инфа, которую у вас не получилось найти https://c-rex.net/projects/samples/ooxml/e1/Part4/OOXML_P4_DOCX_extent_topic_ID0EQB4OB.html

Comment: @aepot, я обновил вопрос и приложил полный xml

Comment: А то что это Office Open XML - надо было догадаться? Ни тегов, не объяснений, ничего. Ответы выше. Постить полный файл было необязательно, достаточно было объяснить, что за формат и откуда взялся и какую задачу вы решаете.

Comment: @aepot, извините не указал, это offilce open xml